# EOFException - how to handle?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm a beginner java programmer following the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial).

I am using a simple Java Program from the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial)'s [Data Streams Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html), and at runtime, it keeps on showing `EOFException`. I was wondering if this was normal, as the reader has to come to the end of the file eventually.

```
import java.io.*;

public class DataStreams {
    static final String dataFile = "F://Java//DataStreams//invoicedata.txt";

    static final double[] prices = { 19.99, 9.99, 15.99, 3.99, 4.99 };
    static final int[] units = { 12, 8, 13, 29, 50 };
    static final String[] descs = {
        "Java T-shirt",
        "Java Mug",
        "Duke Juggling Dolls",
        "Java Pin",
        "Java Key Chain"
    };
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));

            for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++) {
                out.writeDouble(prices[i]);
                out.writeInt(units[i]);
                out.writeUTF(descs[i]);
            }

            out.close(); 

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); // used to be System.err.println();
        }

        double price;
        int unit;
        String desc;
        double total = 0.0;

        try {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile)));

            while (true) {
                price = in.readDouble();
                unit = in.readInt();
                desc = in.readUTF();
                System.out.format("You ordered %d" + " units of %s at $%.2f%n",
                unit, desc, price);
                total += unit * price;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        System.out.format("Your total is %f.%n" , total);
    }
}
```

It compiles fine, but the output is:

```
You ordered 12 units of Java T-shirt at $19.99
You ordered 8 units of Java Mug at $9.99
You ordered 13 units of Duke Juggling Dolls at $15.99
You ordered 29 units of Java Pin at $3.99
You ordered 50 units of Java Key Chain at $4.99
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble(Unknown Source)
        at DataStreams.main(DataStreams.java:39)
Your total is 892.880000.
```

From the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial)'s [Data Streams Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html), it says:

> Notice that DataStreams detects an end-of-file condition by catching [EOFException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html), instead of testing for an invalid return value. All implementations of DataInput methods use EOFException instead of return values.

So, does this mean that catching `EOFException` is normal, so just catching it and not handling it is fine, meaning that the end of file is reached?

If it means I should handle it, please advise me on how to do it.

**EDIT**

From the suggestions, I've fixed it by using `in.available() > 0` for the `while` loop condition.

Or, I could do nothing to handle the exception, because it's fine.

Comment: Removing the `e.printStackTrace();` in the `catch` block will remove the print of the exception's stack trace. Instead to print it you should maybe log it.

Comment: `available()` is not a test for end of stream. The solution in your edit is not valid.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While reading from the file, your are not terminating your loop. So its read all the values and **correctly** throws EOFException on the next iteration of the read at line below:

```
 price = in.readDouble();
```

If you read the documentation, it says:

> Throws:
>
> EOFException - if this input stream reaches the end before reading eight bytes.
>
> IOException - the stream has been closed and the contained input stream does not support reading after close, or another I/O error occurs.

Put a proper termination condition in your while loop to resolve the issue e.g. below:

```
     while(in.available() > 0)  <--- if there are still bytes to read
```

Comment: This loop will exit when there is no more data *currently available to be read,* and *not* just at end of stream. `InputStream.available()` is not a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to handle this would be to terminate your infinite loop with a proper condition.

But since you asked for the exception handling:

Try to use two catches. Your EOFException is expected, so there seems to be no problem when it occures. Any other exception should be handled.

```
...
} catch (EOFException e) {
   // ... this is fine
} catch(IOException e) {
    // handle exception which is not expected
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: that's what they did in the [Data Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html) example. it works too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `while(in.available() != 0)` instead of `while(true)`.

Comment: hasNextLine() isn't part of DataInputStream. This answer is wrong.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't see that. I have changed it now.

Comment: This answer is still wrong. `InputStream.available()` is not a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could write out the number of elements first (as a header) using:

```
out.writeInt(prices.length);
```

When you read the file, you first read the header (element count):

```
int elementCount = in.readInt();

for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
     // read elements
}
```

Comment: yes, i could use that but it would be more inconvenient than @yogendra  singh's suggestion

Comment: @Jon yeah, it's not as safe either (the file might be empty etc.), just shown as an alternative

Answer (score 2):

You may come across code that reads from an `InputStream` and uses the snippet 
`while(in.available()>0)` to check for the end of the stream, rather than checking for an 
EOFException (end of the file).

The problem with this technique, and the `Javadoc` does echo this, is that it only tells you the number of blocks that can be read without blocking the next caller. In other words, it can `return 0` even if there are more bytes to be read. Therefore, the `InputStream available()` method should never be used to check for the end of the stream.

You must use `while (true)` and

```
catch(EOFException e) {
//This isn't problem
} catch (Other e) {
//This is problem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You catch `IOException` which also catches `EOFException`, because it is inherited. If you look at the example from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html) they underlined that you should catch `EOFException` - and this is what they do. To solve you problem catch `EOFException` before `IOException`:

```
try
{
    //...
}
catch(EOFException e) {
    //eof - no error in this case
}
catch(IOException e) {
    //something went wrong
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Beside that I don't like data flow control using exceptions - it is not the intended use of exceptions and thus (in my opinion) really bad style.

Comment: It is *exactly* the 'intended use' for his exception. The problem with your 'principle' is that exceptions *are' a form of flow control.

Answer (score 0):

EOFException being a child of IOException
I prefer it like below ==>

```
try {
        .
        .
        .
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!(e instanceof EOFException)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why? when you can just write a separate `catch (EOFException e)` block? This is pointless.

Comment: Haha... right... I find this hilarious now XD... moreover that catch block should be prior to one for IOException... @user207421

Answer (score -1):

Put your code inside the try catch block:
i.e :

```
try{
  if(in.available()!=0){
    // ------
  }
}catch(EOFException eof){
  //
}catch(Exception e){
  //
}
}
```

Comment: The `available()` test serves no useful purpose.