# Client-Server communication via Socket

Tags: java, client-server

I am trying to send data from my Server to my Client via Socket communication and I am receiving an error at the receiving end.

Here are my code snippets-

Server- This class is called CLIENTConnection and takes care of all the connections from server to client

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import java.io.*;
    public class CLIENTConnection implements Runnable {

private Socket clientSocket;
private BufferedReader in = null;

public CLIENTConnection(Socket client) {
    this.clientSocket = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String clientSelection=in.readLine();
        while (clientSelection != null) {
            switch (clientSelection) {
                case "1":
                    receiveFile();
                    break;
                case "2":

                    System.out.println("inside case 2");
                    String outGoingFileName = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(outGoingFileName);

                      while (outGoingFileName != null) {
                          System.out.println("Inside while loop");
                        sendFile(outGoingFileName);
                   }
                   System.out.println("Out of while");

                    break;

                case "3":
                    receiveFile();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect command received.");
                    break;
            }
            in.close();
            break;
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void receiveFile() {
    try {

        int bytesRead;
        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        String filename = clientData.readUTF();
        System.out.println(filename+" is received on server side");
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("C://Users/Personal/workspace/ClientServer/src/dir/"+filename));
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

        output.close();
        clientData.close();

        System.out.println("File "+filename+" received from client.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Client error. Connection closed.");
    }
}



 public void sendFile(String fileName) {
try {
    //handle file read
    File myFile = new File("C://Users/Personal/workspace/ClientServer/src/dir/"+fileName);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

    //handle file send over socket
    OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

    //Sending file name and file size to the server
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
    dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
    dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
    dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    dos.flush();
    System.out.println("File "+fileName+" sent to client.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("File does not exist!");
} 
}
 }
```

Client Side (Receive File)

```
  public class FileClient {



    private static Socket sock;
    private static String fileName;
    private static BufferedReader stdin;
    private static PrintStream os;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream inFromServer; 



        try 
        {
            sock = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
            stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to the server, try again later.");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        inFromServer= new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        os = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());


        try {
              switch (Integer.parseInt(selectAction())) {
            case 1:
                os.println("1");
                sendFile();
                break;
            case 2:
                os.println("2");
                System.err.print("Enter file name: ");
                fileName = stdin.readLine();
                os.println(fileName);
               receiveFile(fileName);
                break;

            case 3:
                os.println("3");
                Synchronise();

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("not valid input");
        }


        sock.close();


    }


    private static void Synchronise() 
    {
        HashMap<String, Calendar> ClientFileList=getTimeStamp("C://Users/Personal/workspace/ClientServer/Client/");//getting the filename and timestamp of all the files present in client folder. 
        /*System.out.println("Client File List : \n");
        for(String s : ClientFileList.keySet()) 
            System.out.println(s);*/
        HashMap<String, Calendar> ServerFileList=getTimeStamp("C://Users/Personal/workspace/ClientServer/src/dir/");//(HashMap<String, Calendar>) inFromServer.readObject();
        /*System.out.println("\nServer File List : \n");
        for(String s : ClientFileList.keySet()) 
            System.out.println(s);*/
        System.out.println("File comparision output");
        compareTimestamp(ClientFileList,ServerFileList);
    }




    private static void compareTimestamp(HashMap<String, Calendar> ClientFileList, HashMap<String, Calendar> serverFileList) 
    {
        LinkedList<String> fileToUpload=new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> fileToDownload=new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> fileToDeleteFromClient=new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> fileToDeleteFromServer=new LinkedList<String>();
        Calendar clientCalender = null,serverCalendar=null;

        for (String filename : serverFileList.keySet()) 
        {
            serverCalendar=serverFileList.get(filename);
            if(ClientFileList.containsKey(filename))
            {
                clientCalender=ClientFileList.get(filename);
                if(clientCalender.before(serverCalendar))
                {
                    fileToDownload.add(filename);
                }
                else
                {
                    fileToUpload.add(filename);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fileToDeleteFromClient.add(filename);
            }
        }

        for (String filename : ClientFileList.keySet()) 
        {
            clientCalender=ClientFileList.get(filename);
            if(!serverFileList.containsKey(filename))
            {
                fileToDeleteFromServer.add(filename);
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Files to download to client: "+fileToDownload);
        System.out.println("Files to upload to Server: "+fileToUpload);
        System.out.println("Files to delete from client: "+fileToDeleteFromClient);
        System.out.println("Files to delete from Server: "+fileToDeleteFromServer);

        sendFile(fileToDeleteFromServer);

    }


      private static HashMap<String, Calendar> getTimeStamp(String location) 
    {
        HashMap<String,Calendar> fileList = new HashMap<String,Calendar>();
        File dir = new File(location);

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0) 
        {
            System.out.println("No file found");
            //System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
            {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(files[i].lastModified());
                fileList.put(files[i].getName(), calendar);
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }



    public static String selectAction() throws IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("1. Send file.");
        System.out.println("2. Recieve file.");
        System.out.println("3. Synchronize");
        System.out.print("\nMake selection: ");

        return stdin.readLine();
    }

    public static void sendFile() 
    {
        try {
            System.err.print("Enter file name: ");
            fileName = stdin.readLine();

            File myFile = new File("C:/Users/Personal/workspace/ClientServer/Client/"+fileName);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

            //Sending file name and file size to the server
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
            dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
            dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            dos.flush();
            dis.close();
            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" sent to Server.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
        }
    } 

    //receive a list of file to upload to server from client.
    static void sendFile(LinkedList<String> fileList)
    {
        for(String file: fileList)
            sendFile(file);
    }

    public static void sendFile(String filename) {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/Personal/workspace/ClientServer/Client/"+filename);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis;
            try 
            {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

                OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
                dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
                dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                dos.flush();
                dis.close();
                System.out.println("File "+filename+" sent to Server.");

            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    public static void receiveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            int bytesRead;
            InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
             fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_server_"));
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }

            output.close();
            in.close();

            System.out.println("File "+fileName+" received from Server.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

}

It is showing me error at

```
   filename = clientData.readUTF();
```

Please let me know if there are any possible solutions.

Comment: And what error is it showing? Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you trying to assign something to a method argument? You should use a local var, if you don't need it afterwards or return it instead of making the method void if the caller needs it.

Comment: Here is the stacktrace-                                              Dec 03, 2014 6:00:43 AM                                         FileClient receiveFile
SEVERE: null
            java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
 at FileClient.receiveFile(FileClient.java:280)
 at FileClient.main(FileClient.java:53)

Comment: Can you add FileClient.main to the codescnippets in the question, please? You should provide an executable example in such cases ... [ask]

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: You already opened an InputStream from that socket in main method before calling receiveFile. That does not work. You could give that stream to receiveFile method as an argument and use it there.

Comment: I tried doing that, doesnt seem to work. Same exception

Comment: Just a sidenote: Why are most of your methods public static void? I guess that's part of the problem ... Back on topic: I just stumbled upon "case 2" ... how does your server know it has to send file "filename"? I suspect to try to read something that never has been sent. So the stream is empty, when you try to read it.

Comment: I am actually passing the value of fileName to a class called ClientConnection. Initially, it was able to read and display the fileName, but now it is not even doing that. I am totally confused on why it is behaving so weirdly!

Comment: I was talking about the "case 2" in your client code. There is no request to the server to send anything. How do you expect to be able to read something? I suggest going back to the drawing board and review your design. For my taste, there are by far too many "public static" ...

Answer (score 0):

`DataInputStream`s use this exception to signal end of stream. So the exception in might not be an error, and just mean that the data has been sent.

Before reading you will have to check that you have actually received something, and then read it.

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html):
**`This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream.`** `Note that many other input operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.`

Comment: Exactly! The file has been sent but i am not able to capture it.

Comment: Can you suggest on how we can capture it?

Comment: As this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18451336/2895833) suggests, you should add a proper termination condition

Comment: Now, the data is not even being sent.

Comment: Do not use `available()`. It will not do what you expect!

Comment: Fildor thanks for the notice. @ChandrasekharMalladi after Fildors comment I found out that the approach I suggested was wrong, and so I deleted it. Can you please upload your Server class too?

Comment: Added the Server Class as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the file?

```
public static void receiveFile(String fileName) {
        boolean recieving = true;  //new
        while(recieving){ //new
        try {
        int bytesRead;
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
         fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("received_from_server_"));
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

        output.close();
        in.close();

        System.out.println("File "+fileName+" received from Server.");
    }  catch (EOFException e){   // new
        Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        recieving = false;
    }  catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    } //new
}
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't seem to work. Not able to receive file.