# How to handle EOFException?

Tags: java, arrays, randomaccessfile

This code returns an EOFException, any suggestions to what to add or how to handle the issue?

```
public AbstractBlock readBlock(int blockNum, AbstractDBFile f)
        throws IOException {

    DBFile dbf = (DBFile) f;
    byte[] data2 = new byte[4096];
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(dbf.fileName, "r");
    file.seek(4096+blockNum*4096);
    Block b = new Block();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++){
        data2[i] = file.readByte();
    }
    file.close();
    b.setData(data2);
    return b;

}
```

Comment: Even though it's out of the scope of this question, iterating through a file byte by byte is very inefficient. You should use `byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; int count = file.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);`.

Comment: Can you share your exception stacktrace to locate where you are getting the exception? Is it in the file.seek?

Comment: It's not clear if your question is how to handle the exception, or why the exception is happening at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EOFException - how to handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451232/eofexception-how-to-handle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try doing this:

```
public AbstractBlock readBlock(int blockNum, AbstractDBFile f)
    throws IOException {

    DBFile dbf = (DBFile) f;
    byte[] data2 = new byte[4096];
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(dbf.fileName, "r");
    file.seek(4096+blockNum*4096);
    Block b = new Block();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++){
        try{  
            data2[i] = file.readByte();
        }catch(EOFException ex){
            System.out.println("End of file reached!");

            //break the loop
            break;
         }
    }
    file.close();
    b.setData(data2);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `readByte` can throw `IOException` and `EOFException` exceptions

> public final byte **readByte()** throws IOException
>
> Throws:
>
> EOFException - if this file has reached the end.
>
> IOException - if an I/O error occurs.

so you have to put it in a try bloc for example to sea if you realy read something before assigning to the **data2[i]** variable

Answer (score 0):

Say that `blockNum==1` ... does this mean that you should be reading the very first block in the file?  If so, you'd expect to pass `0` to `file.seek()`, but you are actually passing 4096+4096*1 = 8192.  This implies that for a given blockNum, you're actually reading the 2nd block past it.

If so, then for an n-block file, if you pass `n` or `n-1` to this function, you'd get an EOFException.

If the first block is numbered 0, not 1, then you're off by only one block, but the fundamental problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'what should I do when I catch it?', you should stop reading and break. If you mean 'why am I getting it?', your block numbering should start at zero, assuming you are correct about the number of blocks.