# Get EOFException while reading a txt file in Java

Tags: java

I have Google for a while but I still get confused. When I used FileOutputStream to write some texts into a txt file and then use FileInputStream to read my file, everything was right. But when I typed some words manually to my txt file, and then save in UTF-8 format, I got EOFException. 
Here is my input code:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("filename");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
while (in.available()>0) {
    s.append(in.readUTF());
}
in.close();
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: AFAIK `in.available()` returns the number of available bytes while `in.readUTF()` might read a character that spans more than 1 byte. If it's not that you should check your file encoding, maybe the editor you used messed it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EOFException - how to handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451232/eofexception-how-to-handle)

Comment: Btw, try using `new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"))`  which should make reading strings from the file much easier (e.g. there is a `readLine()` method).

Answer (score 1):

- A file that can be read by `readUTF()` must have been written by `writeUTF()`. Not by `FileOutputStream`.
- A file written by `writeUTF()` is not a text file. It is a file of sequences of 16-bit length words and strings in a modified encoding, as described in the Javadoc.
- `available() > 0` is not a valid test for end of file.

As you state it's a text file, and as your code isn't working, I suggest you should be using `BufferedReader.readLine()`. And no `ready()` tests. `readLine()` will return null at end of stream.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc for [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) says the following: "An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream". So it is probably not a good idea to read manually-written text from file using DataInputStream.

Consider using [FileInputStream#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) method if you need to read bytes or [FileReader#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read()) if you need to read characters.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using FileInputStream to read the file, i.e.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    int content;
    while ((content = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        s.append((char) content);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```