# EOF exception and ObjectInputStream.readObject() Error

Tags: java, eclipse, file

This a small part of my code. I want to read the file if it exists. If not, then  create a new one. When I restart the program I want to work with the file that is saved. Eclipse says the error is on  "ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(file);" Not sure why.

```
rooms sbu = new rooms();
    File saveFile = new File("SavedObj.obj");
    if(saveFile.exists() == false)
    {
        System.out.println("No save file found. Creating a new file.");
        try{
            saveFile.createNewFile();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(saveFile);
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(file);
        sbu= (room) inStream.readObject();
    }
```

In the end of my code I store object like this:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
outStream.writeObject(sbu);
outStream.close();
isFinished= true;
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: So what is the question ? The file exists but you get an exception when reading it ?

Comment: yes @SantiBailors

Comment: You could help by mentioning the error message you get, maybe even show the stacktrace if it is an exception. Is it Eclipse that shows a compilation error, or is an exception thrown when you run the code, or ? Maybe these things might be _guessed_ but most people won't care to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451232/eofexception-how-to-handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect `ObjectInputStream` to convert text to objects automatically. `readObject` can only work for the file created by `writeObject` in `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import com.pechen.Person;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        String filename = "person.obj";            
        Person person = new Person();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        out.writeObject(person);
        out.close();

        Person p;
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        p = (Person)in.readObject();
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Read Person: " + p.toString());
     }
}
```