# Server Side EOFException

Tags: java, android, server, chat

I'm trying to write a messaging applicaton, and I'm able to send messages (shown as the server client displays the message correctly) but then kicks my client off of the server. The server prints the following error:

> java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(UnknownSource)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.liftedstarfish.lifte.gpschat0_2.Server$ClientThread.run(Server.java:243)

My Server Class:

```
public class Server {
    // a unique ID for each connection
    private static int uniqueId;
    // an ArrayList to keep the list of the Client
    private ArrayList<ClientThread> al;
    // if I am in a GUI
    private ServerGUI sg;
    // to display time
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    // the port number to listen for connection
    private int port;
    // the boolean that will be turned of to stop the server
    private boolean keepGoing;

    private String name;

    /*
     *  server constructor that receive the port to listen to for connection as parameter
     *  in console
     */
    public Server(int port, String name) {
        this(port, name, null);
    }

    public Server(int port, String name, ServerGUI sg) {
        // GUI or not
        this.sg = sg;
        // the port
        this.port = port;

        this.name = name;
        // to display hh:mm:ss
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        // ArrayList for the Client list
        al = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
    }

    public void start() {
        keepGoing = true;
        /* create socket server and wait for connection requests */
        try 
        {
            // the socket used by the server
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            // infinite loop to wait for connections
            while(keepGoing) 
            {
                // format message saying we are waiting
                display("Server waiting for Clients on " + name + ".");

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();      // accept connection
                // if I was asked to stop
                if(!keepGoing)
                    break;
                ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);  // make a thread of it
                al.add(t);                                  // save it in the ArrayList
                t.start();
            }
            // I was asked to stop
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
                for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                    ClientThread tc = al.get(i);
                    try {
                    tc.sInput.close();
                    tc.sOutput.close();
                    tc.socket.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ioE) {
                        // not much I can do
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                display("Exception closing the server and clients: " + e);
            }
        }
        // something went bad
        catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = sdf.format(new Date()) + " Exception on new ServerSocket: " + e + "\n";
            display(msg);
        }
    }       
    /*
     * For the GUI to stop the server
     */
    protected void stop() {
        keepGoing = false;
        // connect to myself as Client to exit statement 
        // Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        try {
            new Socket("localhost", port);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // nothing I can really do
        }
    }
    /*
     * Display an event (not a message) to the console or the GUI
     */
    private void display(String msg) {
        String time = sdf.format(new Date()) + " " + msg;
        if(sg == null)
            System.out.println(time);
        else
            sg.appendEvent(time + "\n");
    }
    /*
     *  to broadcast a message to all Clients
     */
    private synchronized void broadcast(String message) {
        // add HH:mm:ss and \n to the message
        String time = sdf.format(new Date());
        String messageLf = time + " " + message + "\n";
        // display message on console or GUI
        if(sg == null)
            System.out.print(messageLf);
        else
            sg.appendRoom(messageLf);     // append in the room window

        // we loop in reverse order in case we would have to remove a Client
        // because it has disconnected
        for(int i = al.size(); --i >= 0;) {
            ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
            // try to write to the Client if it fails remove it from the list
            if(!ct.writeMsg(messageLf)) {
                al.remove(i);
                display("Disconnected Client " + ct.username + " removed from list.");
            }
        }
    }

    // for a client who logoff using the LOGOUT message
    synchronized void remove(int id) {
        // scan the array list until we found the Id
        for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
            ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
            // found it
            if(ct.id == id) {
                al.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  To run as a console application just open a console window and: 
     * > java Server
     * > java Server portNumber
     * If the port number is not specified 1500 is used
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start server on port 1500 unless a PortNumber is specified 
        int portNumber = 1500;
        String serverName = "";
        switch(args.length) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid port number.");
                    System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
                    return;
                }
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
                return;

        }
        // create a server object and start it
        Server server = new Server(portNumber, serverName);
        server.start();
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    /** One instance of this thread will run for each client */
    class ClientThread extends Thread {
        // the socket where to listen/talk
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream sInput;
        ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
        // my unique id (easier for deconnection)
        int id;
        // the Username of the Client
        String username;
        // the only type of message a will receive
        ChatMessage cm;
        // the date I connect
        String date;

        // Constructore
        public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
            // a unique id
            id = ++uniqueId;
            this.socket = socket;
            /* Creating both Data Stream */
            System.out.println("Thread trying to create Object Input/Output Streams");
            try
            {
                // create output first
                sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                // read the username
                username = (String) sInput.readObject();
                display(username + " just connected.");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + e);
                return;
            }
            // have to catch ClassNotFoundException
            // but I read a String, I am sure it will work
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            }
            date = new Date().toString() + "\n";
        }

        // what will run forever
        public void run() {
            // to loop until LOGOUT
            boolean keepGoing = true;
            while(keepGoing) {
                // read a String (which is an object)
                try {
                    //Location of Error
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>cm = (ChatMessage) sInput.readObject();<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;              
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
                // the messaage part of the ChatMessage
                String message = cm.getMessage();

                // Switch on the type of message receive
                switch(cm.getType()) {

                case ChatMessage.MESSAGE:
                    broadcast(username + ": " + message);
                    break;
                case ChatMessage.LOGOUT:
                    display(username + " disconnected with a LOGOUT message.");
                    keepGoing = false;
                    break;
                case ChatMessage.WHOISIN:
                    writeMsg("List of the users connected at " + sdf.format(new Date()) + "\n");
                    // scan al the users connected
                    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                        ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
                        writeMsg((i+1) + ") " + ct.username + " since " + ct.date);
                    }
                    break;
                case ChatMessage.ERROR:
                    broadcast(username + "> " + message);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // remove myself from the arrayList containing the list of the
            // connected Clients
            remove(id);
            close();
        }

        // try to close everything
        private void close() {
            // try to close the connection
            try {
                if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
            try {
                if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {};
            try {
                if(socket != null) socket.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        /*
         * Write a String to the Client output stream
         */
        private boolean writeMsg(String msg) {
            // if Client is still connected send the message to it
            if(!socket.isConnected()) {
                close();
                return false;
            }
            // write the message to the stream
            try {
                sOutput.writeObject(msg);
            }
            // if an error occurs, do not abort just inform the user
            catch(IOException e) {
                display("Error sending message to " + username);
                display(e.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

ChatMessage Class:

```
public class ChatMessage extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1112122200L;

    // The different types of message sent by the Client
    // WHOISIN to receive the list of the users connected
    // MESSAGE an ordinary message
    // LOGOUT to disconnect from the Server
    static final int WHOISIN = 0, MESSAGE = 1, LOGOUT = 2, ERROR = 3;
    private int type;
    private String message;

    // constructor
    public ChatMessage(int type, String message) {
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.chat_message);

        final TextView lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_message);

        if(type == MESSAGE)
            lblMessage.setText(message);
    }

    // getters
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Highlight the lines in the code from the stacktrace(Server:243)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: In your ide, find server, and find line 243. You remember what line it is, go back on SO and add a comment or arrow or whatever pointing to this line where you say "this is the line in the stacktrace" - basically show us what line in the Server class that is in the stacktrace

Comment: There you go. I've put arrows around it.

Answer (score 0):

From readObject documentation:

> ClassNotFoundException - Class of a serialized object cannot be found.
>
> InvalidClassException - Something is wrong with a class used by serialization.
>
> StreamCorruptedException - Control information in the stream is inconsistent.
>
> OptionalDataException - Primitive data was found in the stream instead of objects.
>
> IOException - Any of the usual Input/Output related exceptions.

EOFException is a type of IOException, which is thrown when the end of the file is reached. All though this doesn't throw that particular error, it does throw IOException, meaning it can throw EOFException too.

So in your code, you simply add:

```
while(sInput.available() > 0){// > 0 means there are bytes to read.
    //Read
}
```

This (in theory) avoids the EOFException. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451232/eofexception-how-to-handle) for reference

Comment: `InputStream.available()` is not a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc. It also smokes the CPU, and it is also never guaranteed to actually return a positive value. There is also no actual *reason* to 'avoid the `EOFException`'. Just *catch* it.

Answer (score -1):

The peer has closed the connection. You should catch this exception separately, and break out of the loop when you catch it. At present you have no provision at all for this condtion.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Err, 'catch this exception separately': `catch (EOFException exc) { ... }`; 'break out of the loop': `break;`. Is this really such a mystery?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not very good at common sense. I'm still kind of a beginner. This is a skeleton of a program my dad made, and is having me port it to Android.

Comment: Cultivate it. This is a highly logical business. There's nothing in my comment that isn't directly deducible from my answer.