# Socket System EOFException (ObjectInputStream)

Tags: java, sockets, eofexception

Hey i'm coding a socket system with a open src library...
and everytime when i'm sending a message or something i get an EOFException

```
public Datapackage sendMessage(Datapackage message, int timeout) {
    try {
        Socket tempSocket;
        if (secureMode) {
            tempSocket = ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(address.getAddress(),
                    address.getPort());
        } else {
            tempSocket = new Socket();
            tempSocket.connect(address, timeout);
        }

        ObjectOutputStream tempOOS = new ObjectOutputStream(tempSocket.getOutputStream());
        message.sign(id, group);
        tempOOS.writeObject(message);

        ObjectInputStream tempOIS = new ObjectInputStream(tempSocket.getInputStream());
        Object raw = tempOIS.readObject();

        tempOOS.close();
        tempOIS.close();
        tempSocket.close();

        if (raw instanceof Datapackage) {
            return (Datapackage) raw;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        onLogError("[Client] Error while sending message:");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Please can anyone help me :c

Comment: (The exception is in the line " ObjectInputStream tempOIS = new ObjectInputStream(tempSocket.getInputStream());")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EOFException - how to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451232/eofexception-how-to-handle)

Comment: @ThomasEdwin No it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The peer has closed the connection without creating an `ObjectOutputStream`. Almost certainly it isn't using Serialization at all.